# How can we access the datatable individual column searched value to controller(C# .net Mvc) while using the server side processing?

Tags: datatable

I have used datatable individual column searching .

below is my js code:

```
var BindDataTable = function (response) {
    var oTable;
    $("#example").DataTable({

        initComplete: function () {
            // Apply the search
            this.api().columns().every(function () {
                var that = this;

                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change clear', 
                    function () {
                        if (that.search() !== this.value) {


                        that.search(this.value).draw();

                    }
                });
            });
        },
            
     
        "searching": true,
        // dom: '<"class">Blfrtip',
        dom: "<'row mb-3'<'col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 datatableButtonsCon text-right'Bf>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12 datatablesData'tr>>" +
            "<'row mt-4'<'col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6 infoCon'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6 pagCon'p>>",

             "bServerSide": true,
             "sAjaxSource": "/AspNetStudents/GetStudents",
             "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

                $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    data:aoData,
                    url: sSource,
                    success:fnCallback
                })

            },

        "aoColumns": [

            { "mData": "Name" },
            { "mData": "RollNo" },
            { "mData": "CellNo" },
            { "mData": "JoiningDate" },
            { "mData": "ClassName" },
            { "mData": "TotalWithoutAdmission" },
            { "mData": "UserStatus" },

        ]

        });


            oTable = $('#example').DataTable();
            oTable.columns(0).search("data");
            oTable.draw();
```

[image]

I have also attached the backend C# code to access the individual datatable column value to controller.

How can we access the datatable individual column searched value to controller(C# .net Mvc) while using the server side processing?

Answer (score 0):

just as an idea, I know it makes ajax request every time a draw method is called.In this case, the data can be serialized and sent,then the searched data can be accessed by performing a parse operation in the controller.

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: sSource,
                        data: function (data) {
                            data.filters = $(".filter").serialize();
                        },
                        success:fnCallback
                    })

                   // search
                   $(".filter").on("change", function (e) {
                         e.preventDefault();
                         table.draw();
                   });
...
// in controller
// parse request
```